# Get location of image view for rectangle - Android

Tags: android, imageview

I am building a lock screen, I have the following design:

[image: design]

Now the red and green colours will not be there in the end product, it is just to show the padding of the imageviews.

I need to get the coordinates of the red circles in the middle (padding is set to 25dp). I have an on touch method that will register the number button pressed (1 - 3 across, 4 - 6 and 7 - 9)

Here is my current code:

```
public void makeRects(){
    // row 1 rectangles
    b1r = new Rect(b1.getLeft(), b1.getTop(), b1.getRight(), b1.getBottom());
    b2r = new Rect(b2.getLeft(), b2.getTop(), b2.getRight(), b2.getBottom());
    b3r = new Rect(b3.getLeft(), b3.getTop(), b3.getRight(), b3.getBottom());

    // row 2 rectangles
    b4r = new Rect(b4.getLeft(), b4.getTop()+b1.getBottom(), b3.getRight(), b3.getBottom()+b1.getBottom()+b1.getTop());
    b5r = new Rect(b5.getLeft(), b5.getTop()+b2.getBottom(), b5.getRight(), b5.getBottom()+b2.getBottom()+b2.getTop());
    b6r = new Rect(b6.getLeft(), b6.getTop()+b3.getBottom(), b6.getRight(), b6.getBottom()+b3.getBottom()+b3.getTop());

    // row 3 rectangles
    b7r = new Rect(b7.getLeft(), b7.getTop()+b1.getBottom(), b7.getRight(), b7.getBottom()+b1r.height());
    b8r = new Rect(b8.getLeft(), b8.getTop()+b2.getBottom(), b8.getRight(), b8.getBottom()+b2.getBottom()+b2.getTop());
    b9r = new Rect(b9.getLeft(), b9.getTop()+b3.getBottom(), b9.getRight(), b9.getBottom()+b3.getBottom()+b3.getTop());
}
```

However, it is only registering the number button it is at the top of the block (the red or green) and it registers for the whole row (1,2,3 and then 4,5,6,7,8,9 in the second row). I am trying to ONLY get it to register the number button when you hover or drag over each red icon.

How can I do this?

Comment: Row2: Why do you use b4.getTop()+b1.getBottom() ? Wouldn't b4.getTop() be enough.
Also, why don't you put an onTouch handler on all bx objects ?

Comment: Because the b4.getTop() returns the same top value as the b1.getTop().

Comment: and Because then it only registers the click relative to that view, so it will return 1 where ever I click.

Comment: Replied with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make is work with one handler per view:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
b2.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
b3.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
...

// And in myClickListener:

void onClick(View v) {
  if (v == b1) {
    // 1 was pressed.
  } else if (v == b2) {
    // 2 was pressed.
  }
...
}
```

You can also use `getLocationOnScreen`, `getLeft` and other methods returns the coordinates in the parent view.

Comment: I need to be able to drag over the buttons and see what the order is. Not just the click. I already tried this.

Comment: Then getLocationOnScreen is the way to go.